# 1D Bosonisation, equating number of states in Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, bosonization

I was reading von Delft and Schoeller's review (*Bosonization for Beginners*)  and in their Appendix B they prove that the number of states in the fermionic representation's Hilbert space is the same as in the Bosonics. Therefore showing the representations are equivalent. They do this by calculating the grand-canonical ensemble in both representations. This all makes sense to me except one specific line:

"Since this argument is independent of the form of the Hamiltonian, we are free to choose H such that the calculation of the partition functions become tractable."

Then they calculate the partition functions using the standard linearized spectrum, non interacting Hamiltonian for 1D (Eqn. B1 in the review). But I don't see why the argument is independent of the Hamiltonian, surely they've only proved the bosonic representation is complete for the specific Hilbert space corresponding to this Hamiltonian ?

Thanks.